# How to merge/update two List<Map> into one

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

I have 2 lists:

```
        List<Map<String, String>> data1 = new ArrayList<>();
         Map<String, String> m1 = new HashMap(){};
         m1.put("key1","value1")
         Map<String, String> m2 = new HashMap(){};
         m2.put("key2","value2")
        data1.add(m1)
        data1.add(m2)

        List<Map<String, String>> data2 = new ArrayList<>();
         Map<String, String> m22 = new HashMap(){};
         m22.put("key2","chavgedValues2")
        data2.add(m1)
        data2.add(m22)
```

After the merge I want to have List that will contain:

```
"key1","value1"
"key2","chavgedValues2"
```

What is the best way to merge these two lists into one? Like I can implement iterators and so one but I think there should be an easier option something like a stream.
Also there should be a condition, that if a Entry.Key from data1 is equal to Entry.Key from data2 than take only map from data 2. Something like SQL joiner.

Comment: read the javadoc https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#addAll(java.util.Collection). same keys will be overridden by default

Comment: The requirement isn't clear enough, at least to me. Could you share an example of two such lists and the result you'd like to get for them?

Comment: You have a list of maps. How do you decide which map of data1 you want to merge with which map of data2? By list-index? I would start with merging two maps.

Comment: @Mureinik  i have updated description

Comment: why have list of map ? if each map of a list contains key that are unique then merge map of each list then overide value from the first map to the over one, one?

Comment: Do you want the final output to be one list of map or just one map containing all values from all the list of maps that you've? Also, there are multiple maps inside list1, how do I know into which map should I add a Key found from list2?

Answer (score 0):

```
data1.addAll(data2);
```

Would be the easiest way, but then you can´t do conditional checking if the same Key exists in two or more maps.

So I would do it manually with iterators and loops. I can´t see that the stream function would make it easier with this.